# Bulk Insert if not exists without primary key

Tags: sql-server, iis, bulkinsert, exists

I am using a bulk insert to take a `.txt` file and import it into a SQL Server database.

The table is defined:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.server1 
(
    [DATE] [VARCHAR] (16) NULL,
    [TIME] [VARCHAR] (16) NULL,
    [s-ip] [VARCHAR] (16) NULL,
    [cs-method] [VARCHAR] (8) NULL, 
    [cs-uri-stem] [VARCHAR] (255) NULL,
    [cs-uri-query] [VARCHAR] (2048) NULL,
    [s-port] [VARCHAR] (4) NULL,
    [s-username] [VARCHAR] (50) NULL,
    [c-ip] [VARCHAR] (16) NULL,
    [cs(User-Agent)] [VARCHAR] (1024) NULL,
    [cs(Cookie)] [VARCHAR] (1024) NULL,
    [cs(Referer)] [VARCHAR] (4096) NULL, 
    [sc-STATUS] [INT] NULL,
    [sc-substatus] [INT] NULL,
    [sc-win32-STATUS] [INT] NULL,
    [sc-bytes] [DECIMAL] NULL,
    [cs-bytes] [DECIMAL] NULL,
    [time-taken] [INT] NULL,
)
```

The bulk insert

```
BULK INSERT dbo.server1
FROM 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\log.txt'
WITH (
     FIRSTROW = 2,
     FIELDTERMINATOR = ' ',
     ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

The `.txt` file looks like (IIS Log)

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2017-05-31 00:00:00
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Cookie) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status sc-bytes cs-bytes time-taken
2017-05-31 00:00:00 ::1 POST /support/webservice/BatchService.asmx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+Win32;+WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5) - - 401 2 5 6765 629 2
2017-05-31 00:05:15 ::1 POST /support/webservice/BatchService.asmx - 80 AD\wmisbatch ::1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+Win32;+WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5) - - 200 0 0 734 820 314898
2017-05-31 01:00:00 ::1 POST /support/webservice/BatchService.asmx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+Win32;+WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5) - - 401 2 5 6765 629 1
```

My issue is that I have no primary key and need to check if an entire row exists. I am not inserting specific values either as I have found plenty of examples for both. The reason I ask is because I could potentially want to run the `bulk insert` manually or scheduled and do not want duplicate data.

What is the best way to do a `not exists` or procedure when I do not have a primary key or inserting specific values?

I have a solution using `Union` and a temp table but I would like to avoid that if possible.